# Change environment in the test instead of command line arg

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, nightwatch.js

I want to be able to change the environment of a test in the code instead of the command line, example:

http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#test-settings

`nightwatch --env xpto` will change to the environment in the config of the nighwatch called xpto.
I want to do that in the test,

For example...

```
export default {
before : function (client) {
    //This is just for explanation.
    client.options.setEnvironment("xpto");
},
...
...
```

There is some kind of function or something to do this?

My case scenario is...

I have a docker image to run the tests and i want to have one environment without user agent and another one with it in the same command...

Then i should just have 2 testsFiles one using the default environment and the other one using the `xpto`environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set environment variable to do that https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env (docker does set few envs you can use that info)

Comment: Build another container please, it is not worth to do this task.